# migrations: t.references doesn't allow index name to be specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following in a migration:

```
create_table :model_with_a_long_name do |t|
  t.references :other_model_with_an_equally_long_name, index: true
end
```

That produces an index with too long of a name for Postgres.

Is there a way to manually specify the index name (without adding the integer column and the index separately)?

Something like the following:

```
create_table :model_with_a_long_name do |t|
  t.references :other_model_with_an_equally_long_name, index: true, index_name: 'model_and_other'
end
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I handle too long index names in a Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443740/how-do-i-handle-too-long-index-names-in-a-ruby-on-rails-activerecord-migration)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

According to [Rails code for `references`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8e4ab75aa21cc482fc7e9c2c269ac37a40340dfa/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L351), you can do so, providing `index` a `Hash` with options, the one you need called `:name`, so:

```
t.references :my_field, index: { name: 'my_index_name' }
```

Comment: I love Rails, so simple!

Comment: The order threw me off. I had index at the very end before null and foreign key.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Specify it longhand:

```
  t.integer :othermodel_id
  ...
end
add_index :thismodel, :othermodel_id, name: 'othermodel_index'
```